# Java: Pass a fake variable to method

Tags: java, methods, minecraft-forge

I have a boolean-method that uses an Object as an argument. I can't change it and can't extend the class, but I need it to return true for an argument that would return false otherwise. So, I was wondering wether I can give it somethign like a "fake argument". It references my object, but instead gets a different parameter I decide. Here is the code, if you are curious.

```
   protected boolean mayPlaceOn(BlockState p_51042_, BlockGetter p_51043_, BlockPos p_51044_) {
      return p_51042_.is(BlockTags.DIRT) || p_51042_.is(Blocks.FARMLAND);
   }
```

(Yes, it is for a Minecraft Mod) I want to set BlockState p_51042_ to Blocks.FARMLAND whenever it calls for, for example Blocks.STONE.

Comment: You can subclass BlockState (if it's not final) and make the `is` method do what you want.

Comment: What you're trying to do doesn't look very healthy. If the method is protected and it's not your code calling it (meaning you're not extending the class), then doing so would probably result into undefined behaviours. What is the real need and how do you get this code invoked?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ The method is used by every "plant" Object in Minecrafts native environment and called periodically. These plants destroy themselves when they arent sitting on FARMLAND. I need them to survive on different blocks, that is all.

Comment: How do mods that provide custom farm land, such as [Mystical Agriculture](https://github.com/BlakeBr0/MysticalAgriculture/blob/1.18/src/main/java/com/blakebr0/mysticalagriculture/block/InfusedFarmlandBlock.java#L33) do that?

Comment: I have zero knowledge of Minecraft (not only the SDK but not even the game). Though, if your plant needs to survive elsewhere, I'd intuitively say that you want your own plant (extends native plant) and you want to override their native method to make them survive where native plants can't survive

Comment: @MatteoNNZ That would work, but typically isn't recommended. Blocks are called a lot, and replacing them can cause a lot of unforseeable behavior.

Comment: When you say you "can't extend the class", do you mean that you can't extend the class with the `mayPlaceOn` method, or that you can't extend `BlockState`?